# Is my while loop looping too fast for my method?

Tags: java, multithreading, loops, methods, while-loop

I have a method `chatHandler();` which contains quite a bit of code. It also runs on a separate thread as the rest of the program.

In the `main` method I have a while loop running this as long as `running == true` like so:

```
while (running) {
  chatHandler();
}
```

(Question 1) My question is that since I'm running `chatHandler();` on a different thread... could the method be called faster than the code in it can run? The outcome of my program seems to tell me that this is the case.

This also seems to be too specific of a question for Google, just... before you roast me. So if Question 1 is yes, then how do I make sure that the `while` function only loops as fast as the `chatHandler();` can handle?

Here is the code in my `chatHandler();` method:

```
public static void chatHandler() {
  new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {

      LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
      int hour = now.get(ChronoField.HOUR_OF_DAY);
      int minute = now.get(ChronoField.MINUTE_OF_HOUR);
      int second = now.get(ChronoField.SECOND_OF_MINUTE);

      String hourSyntax = Integer.toString(hour);
      String minuteSyntax = Integer.toString(minute);
      String secondSyntax = Integer.toString(second);

      if (hour < 10) {
        hourSyntax = "0" + hourSyntax;
      }

      if (minute < 10) {
        minuteSyntax = "0" + minuteSyntax;
      }

      if (second < 10) {
        secondSyntax = "0" + secondSyntax;
      }

      String chatChecker = "[" + hourSyntax + ":" + minuteSyntax + ":" + secondSyntax +
        "] [Server thread/INFO]: <";
      //System.out.println(chatChecker);
      outputPretext = outputLine.substring(0, 34);

      if (outputPretext.equals(chatChecker)) {
        userNameArray = outputLine.split("~");
        preUserName = userNameArray[1];
        userNameArray2 = preUserName.split(">");
        userName = userNameArray2[0];
        teamCheck = outputLine.substring(34, 36);
        playerMessageArray = outputLine.split(">");
        playerMessage = playerMessageArray[1].substring(1);

        /**
        twitchRank = "§T§r§~";
        youTubeRank = "§Y§r§~";
        owner = "§O§r§~";
        admin = "§A§r§~";
        spookRating1 = "§1§r§~";
        spookRating2 = "§2§r§~";
        member = "§M§r§~";
        */

        //chatCurseReplace();
        //chatSpamCheck();
        //mutedPlayer();

        switch (teamCheck) {

          case "�T":
            try {
              writer.append("/tellraw @a [\"\",{\"text\":\"* \"},{\"text\":\"Twitch \",\"bold\":true,\"color\":\"dark_purple\"},{\"text\":\"" + userName + "\",\"color\":\"blue\"},{\"text\":\" » " + playerMessage + "\"}]");
              writer.newLine();
              writer.flush();
            } catch (IOException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
            }
            break;

          case "�Y":
            try {
              writer.append("/tellraw @a [\"\",{\"text\":\"* You\"},{\"text\":\"Tube \",\"bold\":true,\"color\":\"red\"},{\"text\":\"" + userName + "\",\"bold\":true,\"color\":\"blue\"},{\"text\":\" \",\"bold\":true},{\"text\":\" » " + playerMessage + "\"}]");
              writer.newLine();
              writer.flush();
            } catch (IOException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
            }
            break;

          case "�O":
            try {
              writer.append("/tellraw @a [\"\",{\"text\":\"* \"},{\"text\":\"Owner \",\"bold\":true,\"color\":\"dark_red\"},{\"text\":\"" + userName + "\",\"color\":\"red\"},{\"text\":\" > " + playerMessage + "\"}]");
              writer.newLine();
              writer.flush();
            } catch (IOException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
            }
            break;

          case "�A":
            try {
              writer.append("/tellraw @a [\"\",{\"text\":\"* \"},{\"text\":\"Admin \",\"bold\":true,\"color\":\"dark_red\"},{\"text\":\"" + userName + "\",\"color\":\"red\"},{\"text\":\" » " + playerMessage + "\"}]");
              writer.newLine();
              writer.flush();
            } catch (IOException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
            }
            break;

          case "�1":
            try {
              writer.append("/tellraw @a [\"\",{\"text\":\"* \"},{\"text\":\"[\",\"color\":\"dark_green\"},{\"text\":\"S\",\"color\":\"green\"},{\"text\":\"]\",\"color\":\"dark_green\"},{\"text\":\" \"},{\"text\":\"" + userName + "\",\"color\":\"blue\"},{\"text\":\" » " + playerMessage + "\"}]");
              writer.newLine();
              writer.flush();
            } catch (IOException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
            }
            break;

          case "�2":
            try {
              writer.append("/tellraw @a [\"\",{\"text\":\"* \"},{\"text\":\"[\",\"color\":\"dark_green\"},{\"text\":\"Spook\",\"color\":\"green\"},{\"text\":\"]\",\"color\":\"dark_green\"},{\"text\":\" \"},{\"text\":\"" + userName + "\",\"color\":\"blue\"},{\"text\":\" » " + playerMessage + "\"}]");
              writer.newLine();
              writer.flush();
            } catch (IOException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
            }
            break;

          case "�M":
            try {
              writer.append("/tellraw @a [\"\",{\"text\":\"* \"},{\"text\":\"" + userName + "\",\"color\":\"dark_gray\"},{\"text\":\"  » \"},{\"text\":\"" + playerMessage + "\",\"color\":\"gray\"}]");
              writer.newLine();
              writer.flush();
            } catch (IOException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
            }
            break;

          case "NO":
            break;

          default:
            try {
              writer.append("say Chat Error: no team");
              writer.newLine();
              writer.flush();
            } catch (IOException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
            }
            break;
        }
        outputLine = "****************************************************************";
      }
    }
  }).start();
}
```

That's about all, thanks!

Comment: I need more context to explain better; but, based on your code, a better way to do this would be to always have a thread running in the background (to handle the chat messages) rather than starting a new thread every time... (Which it seems like you are doing, once again out of context.)

Comment: Why are you using threads in the first place?  (And yes, unless you add specific synchronization primitives, there is no guarantee about the order in which your code runs.)

Comment: Looks like you'll be launching thousands of threads.  Every call to `chatHandler()` launches a new thread and returns immediately.  You should fill up memory fairly quickly, not to mention giving the thread dispatcher a headache trying to run so many threads simultaneously.

Comment: @Kaelinator It seems you want to make sure that `chatHandler` method is invoked only after the previous invocation has completed. If so, Instead of spawning a new thread you can do that work in the same thread as that of `while` loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer to question 1: *Yes! Oh Yes! Definitely! Absolutely!*

`chatHandler()` creates a new thread and starts it, then returns immediately.

The thread has barely, if at all, begun to run at that time.

Your loop then turns around and call it again!

By the time the *first* thread has even gotten to the point of *entering* the `run()` method, your loop may have kicked off dozens of threads.

I wouldn't be surprised if your code ran into thread-starvation.

---

So, ask yourself this question: Why did you try to run the code in a different thread?

If you only want to run the loop as fast as the code can handle it, just run the code directly.

Comment: I created a new thread for that method because I've got other methods running, things like thread.sleep and such. Is there any other way to loop as fast as the method can go (without having to code it directly)? Like having a boolean set at the end of the method?

Comment: Got it fixed, I now have it so that it calls the `chatHandler();` and within that thread it will run the while loop. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are not running chathandler() on a different thread.  What you are running on a different thread is the run() method of your anonymous Runnable subclass.  The chathandler() method itself is running in your main thread.

Each time you call chathandler(), it creates a new instance of your anonymous Runnable subclass and starts it, then returns.  This happens as fast as your main thread can loop, irrespective of how fast the Runnable's run() method runs.  That results in a lot of copies of your Runnable, each one running its run() method in its own thread.

Based on what you seem to be expecting, you don't seem to need multiple threads.  Just call your Runnable's run() method directly from your main thread, instead of calling it indirectly through the chathandler() method.

Answer (score -1):

There are no guarantees about the order in which concurrent code runs, unless you write them yourself.  In this case, you're most likely going to spawn many thousands of threads, but it's timing dependent.

It looks to me that in this case you are abusing the concurrent programming facilities.

Concurrent code exists only because in some relatively rare cases it can improve performance.  *It is a hack.*

So to answer question 1:  *yes*.

To answer question 2:  you could wait for the thread to run to completion, or, you could simply stop using threads.  Just call the function instead of trying to use a feature you don't need.  This is because the goal of threads is to do more than one thing at once, but waiting for each thread to run to completion before spawning a new one defeats the entire point.

Comment: I wouldn't say that multi-threading is rare or a hack. It's very common and absolutely required.

Comment: @Andreas Multi-threading is not a good choice for the large majority of problems, depending, of course, on what you work on. In 90% of cases (like the OP's) you're better off running code sequentially.  I'm calling concurrency a hack because it exists only to improve the performance of programs.  It increases complexity only for a (sometimes incredible) performance benefit, yet it shouldn't be used for any other reason.